# How to set duration of Transform.translate() animation in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am currently trying to learn flutter and trying to make a tic tac toe game in flutter. I want my game such that when I tap on a tile, the circles and crosses fall from above. I am trying to implement this using `Transform.Translate()` twice. Like this

```
GridTile(
          child: Transform.translate(
            child: Transform.translate(
              child: Image.asset(
                MultiPlayerGameLogic().imageProvider(i),
                fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
              ),
              offset: Offset(0, -1000),
            ),
            offset: Offset(0, 1000),
          ),
        )
```

But this happens instantly and no animation can be seen. I want to set the duration of outer `Transform.translate()`. But cannot find any way to do so.

Comment: because `Transform.translate` does not provide any animation - you would need `AnimatedAlign` / `AlignTransition` / `SlideTransition` or similar widgets

Comment: Can you show me how to implement any of them for the animation to work as intended?

Comment: Just wrap your widget using the above mentioned widget and look out the documentation about the widget that you are using, that's how you should learn and if you stuck at any point, then let us know or post another question. Good Luck!

Comment: Okay. I'll try. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

##### Screenshot:

[image]

---

##### Code:

You need to wrap your Transform widget into another widget like an `AnimatedBuilder` or `AnimatedWidget`.

For example:

```dart
class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final AnimationController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    ); // <-- Set your duration here.
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: _controller,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0, 100 * _controller.value),
            child: FlutterLogo(size: 100),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm using `Transform.translate()` with `Animation`

```dart
    AnimationController controller;
    Animation<double> animation;

    @override
    void initState() {
       super.initState();
        controller = new AnimationController(
           duration: Duration(seconds: 3), vsync: this)..addListener(() => 
           setState(() {}));
        animation = Tween(begin: -500.0, end: 500.0).animate(controller);
        controller.forward();
     }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
          body: Transform.translate(
           child: Image.asset('image_path'),
           offset: Offset(animation.value, 0.0),
      ));
    }

    @override
    void dispose() {
      controller.dispose();
      super.dispose();
    }
```